# Mule deployment - Invalid content found Data mapper config

Tags: mule, esb, enterprise

I'm using the trial version of Mule Standalone EE server (checked the error message). I can run my project within Anypoint Studio, but when I deploy to Mule Standalone, it fails with the error - Invalid content was found starting with element 'data-mapper:config'
Anyone has any idea on this error?

I believe even I use Tomcat server, I would end up with same error or would it be using any other run time.

Comment: What is the Mule Standalone version ?

Comment: Mule-Enterprise-Standalone 3.7 and Java is 1.7. Even the run time within Anypoint Studio shows only EE where it's working properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Datamapper is not included in 3.7 anymore. So if you use it you must use the latest 3.6 runtime.
But still when deploying through Anypoint Studio, it should still work normally.

It says in 3.7 datamapper was replaced by another enterprise feature called DataWeave.
As per this reference :- http://forum.mulesoft.org/mulesoft/topics/developing-applications-using-mule-soft-community-ide-and-enterprise-ide-and-deploying-in-community-standalone-and-enterprise-standalone
also here :- https://developer.mulesoft.com/docs/display/EARLYACCESS/Including+the+DataMapper+Plugin

Answer (score -1):

Thanks Anirban for the response. Found the resolution in second link you provided.
However the second link informs us to download the plugin zip, which I couldnt' find anywhere.
Instead, I searched in the Anypoint studio files and found data-mapper-plugin folder which I copied to MuleServer\Plugins location. And it worked.

Comment: this should be a comment in the answer provided by @Anirban

Comment: I didn't have enough points to add the comment, that's the reason for my comment despite accepting Anirban's answer as the correct one.